# Create a new Virtualenv

Tags: command-line, system-installation, software-installation

I am a beginner user in Ubuntu , I have some issue. so please help me.

```
ghaas0ab@dem0:~$ pip install virtualenv
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (15.1.0)
```

What's mean this message ? and how to install virtualenv?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

The message means you already have installed virtualenv, so there's no need to install it again.

In order to activate it, try to copy + paste following commands:

`virtualenv -p python3 .venv`

`source .venv/bin/activate`

for checking your pip packages:

`pip freeze`

for deactivating:

`deactivate`

if this does not work for you try this way:

`python3 -m venv .venv`

but in this case try to ignore the `pkg-resources==0.0.0` in your venv  otherwise it will give conflict in requirements, ones you transfer your files to someone else.

Comment: Hi sebuhi, welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please try to use proper grammar when posting answers.

Comment: @Zanna You already corrected it.

Comment: @AaronFranke Sorry for that, I was too sleepy at that time, did not check my grammar. that is my fault, thank you Zanna for correcting the sentences.

Answer (score 1):

It means that virtualenv tool is already installed in your local
   system. Now to activate virtual environment in your laptop, proceed
   as follows:

Create the virtualenv:

```
    $ cd <working_dir> # move into the dir where you want to create venv
    $ virtualenv venv
```

NOTE: If you have both Python 3 and Python 2 installed, try this command instead of `virtualenv venv`, 
   it creates an isolated Python 3 environment called venv in your 
   current directory

```
    $ virtualenv venv -p $(which python3)
```

Run venv:

```
    $ source venv/bin/activate
```

Exit:

```
    (venv)$ deactivate # to exit the environment
```